# Issue with permissions in a node.js module

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I built an npm module named `emeraldfw` and published it. My `package.json` file is

```
{
  "name": "emeraldfw",
  "version": "0.6.0",
  "bin": "./emeraldfw.js",
  "description": "Emerald Framework is a language-agnostig web development framework, designed to make developer's lives easier and fun while coding.",
  "main": "emeraldfw.js",
  "directories": {
    "example": "examples",
    "test": "test"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "mocha"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/EdDeAlmeidaJr/emeraldfw.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "web",
    "development",
    "framework",
    "language",
    "agnostic",
    "react"
  ],
  "author": "Ed de Almeida",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/EdDeAlmeidaJr/emeraldfw/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/EdDeAlmeidaJr/emeraldfw#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "jshint": "^2.9.4",
    "mocha": "^3.3.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsonfile": "^3.0.0",
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "vorpal": "^1.12.0"
  }
}
```

As you may see, I declared a `"bin": "./emeraldfw.js"` binary, which corresponds to the application itself. The `package.json` documentations says this is going to create a link to the application executable at node.js bin/ directory. This worked fine, but when I install it globally (`npm install emeraldfw -g`) and then run it from the command line I receive an error messsage[image]

All other node modules are working fine and my application is passing in all tests and when I run it directly inside the development directory (with `node emeraldfw.js`) it works really fine.

I'm not a node.js expert and after having fought this error for two days, here I am to ask for help.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I checked the permissions for my node binary (emeraldfw.js) and it belongs to edvaldo:edvaldo, my user and group. And it is with executable permissions set. I should have no permission issues inside my own area with these settings, don't you think?

Comment: Please make sure that you have installed npm as the current user instead of the administrator (sudo). You will not be able to install global packages as current user if you have installed node and npm with sudo. Also, check this link: https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions

Comment: I installed node.js (and so npm) as the current user, myself. So this should not be a problem at all. I'll check the documentation you mentioned, @AliDemirci, thanks!

Comment: I checked the permissions for `npm`, @AliDemirci, and it was installed as the current user.

Comment: I watched the video there and it is about permissions to install new modules with `npm`, which is not the case. My module installs perfectly. It is when I try to run it that I get this error, @AliPoder.

Comment: Well first of all I tried to install your package globally on my Windows machine, and it tried to start it with Windows Script Host instead of Node. Could you please try adding `#!/usr/bin/env node` to the first line of emeraldfw.js file at root and retry installing it from npm as global package, please?

Comment: I'll do that @AliPoder. Just a second.

Comment: It worked @AliPoder! Would you please post this as an answer, so I can accept it. I thank you a lot for your help.

Comment: Glad it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, shebang issue here.

Before creating npm modules, you need read every single line of it's documentation.

As it stated [here](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) you need to use shebang to let your operating system know that it should run with node instead of operating system's own script execution hosts.

> Please make sure that your file(s) referenced in bin starts with
>   `#!/usr/bin/env node`, otherwise the scripts are started without the node executable!

So, by using shebang on an npm module, you tell the os to create platform specific executables which let it use node to run the script. A `.cmd` file on Windows for example.

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to install as su?

Comment: Not really. Because all modules worked fine without this. And consider the fact that I am inside my own user area and node.js modules are installed in user space. This should not be neccessary at all, from my point of view.

Comment: I checked the permissions for my node binary (`emeraldfw.js`) and it belongs to edvaldo:edvaldo, my user and group. And it is with executable permissions set. I should have no permission issues inside my own area with these settings, don't you think?

Comment: if you want to install globally with -g, on linux and mac, I believe you have to install as su (super user).Btw your code worked, right?